# Change $p \rightarrow -p$ $ d^{3}p$ invariant

Tags: integration

I am unsure how to change of variables $p \rightarrow -p$ is valid. I would have thought the integral would pick up a - on the $d^{3}p$?

David Tong Notes https://i.stack.imgur.com/zerx0.png

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Something in the previous edit broke something... so I reverted...

Answer (score 1):

The integral picks up two minus signs - one from the substitution, and another from changing the direction of integration. For a simpler example:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \, dx = \int_{\infty}^{-\infty}-f(-t)\,dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(-t) \, dt.$$

Comment: I think the "$d^3p$" refers to a 3-D integral, so it'd be $(-1)^3$ from the change of sign in the "measure", and then another $(-1)^3$ from the change of orders of the corresponding three integerals from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

Comment: Yes, I agree entirely.

Comment: Ah yes, that would be it. Thank you for the help.